# Socket.IO messages usually not received by Android client when emitted shortly after connection

Tags: android, reactjs, socket.io

I'm working on a websocket game. The general flow goes like this:

1. The client creates a socket.IO connection to the server.
2. The client emits a message requesting to join a game.
3. The server adds the client to the game and immediately sends a few messages representing the current state of the game.

In step three, everything works fine on desktop, but when I run the code in Chrome on Android, the events from the server in step three usually are not received (but sometimes are). Later events are received.

On the server, if I add a two second delay between receiving the request to join the game (step 2) and emitting the current state of the game (step 3), it works consistently on Android too.

On the client, the socket connection is created and the events are subscribed in componentDidMount as below:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.socket = socketIO(getKanjiGameServer());

  const { location } = this.props;
  const query = queryString.parse(location.search);

  if (!query.username) {
    window.$('#chooseUsernameModal').modal();
    return;
  }

  this.socket.on(socketEvents.Server.NO_SUCH_GAME, () => {
    window.$('#noSuchGameModal').modal();
  });

  /*
   * A bunch of other events get subscribed here
   */

  this.socket.emit(socketEvents.Client.JOIN_GAME, query);
}
```

Am I opening the connection in the wrong place or something? Based on my testing I am confident that the server is emitting the messages but the handlers in the client are not executing.

I have a test server online [here](http://104.248.186.222), the full relevant client code is [here](https://github.com/mistval/kotobaweb/blob/master/react-frontend/src/kanjigame/game.jsx), and the server code is [here](https://github.com/mistval/kotobaweb/blob/master/express-backend/quiz/start.js). (I've added a delay in the server code so this problem probably won't occur on the test server... assuming the magic number is long enough for you)

Breakpoints before the server emits get hit, but breakpoints in the client event handlers do not get hit for the events that get sent immediately after joining the game.

EDIT: Based on comments, I changed the code where the JOIN_GAME message is emitted to the following:

```
console.warn('test');

this.socket.on('error', err => {
  console.warn(err);
});

this.socket.on('connect_error', err => {
  console.warn(err);
});

this.socket.on('reconnect_error', err => {
  console.warn(err);
});

this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  this.socket.emit(socketEvents.Client.JOIN_GAME, query);
});
```

In remote debugging, the 'test' warn prints to the console, but no errors are printed. I also tried emitting the event outside of the 'connect' event, as I was doing before, but no errors are printed that way either. As before, this works consistently in Chrome on desktop, but only works sometimes in Chrome on Android, unless I add a delay in the server before responding to the JOIN_GAME message.

Comment: You have determined that the modals are not opening, but are you sure the event handlers are not, in fact, executing? By the way, you can debug Chrome on your device using Chrome on your dev box: [Remote Debugging in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/) - it can be very helpful.

Comment: It's not just the modal, there are 10-15 events (omitted due to length), and when a new user joins, the server emits a history of the last 50 events. None of them are firing in this case, as far as I can tell by putting window.alert()s and breakpoints in them. Remote debugging in chrome shows no errors and breakpoints aren't hit.

Comment: I would do a couple things, to try and understand the problem better: 1.) Implement `socket.on('error',...)` and dump the results to alert() or something. 2.) Implement `socket.on('connect',...)`, and emit `JOIN_GAME` from there, instead. I have a suspicion the socket is not guaranteed to be connected immediately after `socketIO()` returns. Might want to implement `socket.on('disconnect',...)`, too -- you never know when your connection's going to go bad.

Comment: @greeble31 thanks for the great suggestions, I was really hopeful when I read your comment, but alas am still not having any luck. I updated my question describing what I did based on your comment. If you don't have any other ideas, I think I'm going to live with the delay in there for now, and later maybe try debugging into socket.io to see if I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: Well I was about to suggest some breakpoint locations in socket.io :) But I'll also point out that you can read everything socket.io is sending by viewing the network debugging pane. Data generally goes out in a POST and comes back via the response to a GET. Just as a way to verify that Chrome is getting good results on the XHRs.